# How to add QAction menu items to dock icon

Tags: macos, qt, menu, dock, qaction

How do you insert a custom `QAction` as a menu item, not in the menubar, but in the dock icon on Mac?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Used

```
void qt_mac_set_dock_menu(QMenu *menu);
```

which has to be declared first:

```
extern void qt_mac_set_dock_menu(QMenu *);
```